# change image size of the any one of the post image

Tags: php, wordpress

I have displayed a recent post content which is an image, i need to change image size of that particular image.

Comment: Change the image size using some desktop-application and re-upload with the same file name.

Comment: `<img src="whatever.jpg" width="$new_width" height="$new_height" />`

Comment: what problem are you facing in changing the size of the image....

Comment: @Marc B: this is a very bad practice.

Comment: @fabrik: OP didn't say where the images had to be resized...

Answer (score 0):

As @fabrik points out @Marc B's solution works, though it's not elegant.

Though, it works. If it's the first image in the post, then filter out the first  tag from the wp_content then apply the filter to forcibly set the width and/or height.

If the image attached is the featured image or a custom attribute, just do the same thing except filter that data item instead of the post content.